# Updating bare repo files to git

Tags: git

I have a bare repo and I edited the files directly without doing a `git commit -a -m` command because I was rushing, is it possible to update the git to know the changes I have made? Because when I do a `git status` on the bare repo I get a:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

**EDIT:** This is what I do for the bare repo:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME=$1

mkdir git/$1
cd git/$1
git init --bare
echo "git clone /root/git/$1 /tmp/git/$1" >> hooks/post-receive
echo "cp -rp /tmp/git/$1/* /var/www/$1" >> hooks/post-receive
echo "rm -rf /tmp/git/$1" >> hooks/post-receive
```

So what I did was edit directly the files at `/var/www/$1/` directory.

Comment: What do you get from git-stash? I've been caught in this trap before but ended up re-cloning from somewhere else..

Comment: Which files did you edit directly? A bare repo has no working copy.

Comment: I updated the question, please reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you could do essentially the reverse of what that `post-receive` hook is doing (untested):

```
git clone /root/git/<repo> /tmp/<tmprepo>
cp -rp /var/www/* /tmp/<tmprepo>
cd /tmp/<tmprepo>
git checkout <branch_to_put_cruft_on>
git commit -a -m "collecting misc edits from web tree"
git push origin <branch_to_put_cruft_on>
cd -
rm -rf /tmp/<tmprepo>
```

If there are additional files in `/var/www` beyond the stuff from the repo, the `cp` catches more than necessary, but the `git commit -a` should ignore files that are not currently being tracked.

You could probably also accomplish this with `git`s `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options, and that might give a cleaner solution, but I've not played with those extensively. Something along these lines (also untested, YMMV, blah, blah...):

```
git clone /root/git/<repo> /tmp/<tmprepo>
cd /tmp/<tmprepo>
git checkout <somebranch>
git --git-dir=/tmp/<tmprepo>/.git --work-tree=/var/www commit -a -m "collect edits"
git push origin <somebranch>
cd -
rm -rf /tmp/<tmprepo>
```

To be even more careful, rather than doing `git commit -a`, use the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options with the appropriate series of `git add`s and do a proper commit.